# Stryker can't find .csproj file even though it's passed in command

Tags: c#, .net-core, stryker

When I try to run Stryker with the below command it fails saying it can't find a `.csproj` file. The file exists at the configured location though:

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\git\my_pkg>dotnet stryker --solution-path ".\My.Project.sln" --test-runner DotnetTest --project-file ".\test\My.Project.Tests\My.Project.Tests.csproj"

   _____ _              _               _   _ ______ _______
  / ____| |            | |             | \ | |  ____|__   __|
 | (___ | |_ _ __ _   _| | _____ _ __  |  \| | |__     | |
  \___ \| __| '__| | | | |/ / _ \ '__| | . ` |  __|    | |
  ____) | |_| |  | |_| |   <  __/ |    | |\  | |____   | |
 |_____/ \__|_|   \__, |_|\_\___|_| (_)|_| \_|______|  |_|
                   __/ |
                  |___/


 Version: 0.20.0 (beta)

[10:41:49 INF] Time Elapsed 00:00:00.8016192
Stryker.NET failed to mutate your project. For more information see the logs below:

No .csproj file found, please check your project directory at C:\Users\Me\Documents\git\my_pkg
```

Why is the file not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*--project-file* should point to the project you intend to mutate, not the unit test project.  That is, if *My.Project.csproj* is the project you are testing and *My.Project.Tests.csproj* are the accompanying unit tests, then what I would normally do is navigate to the folder containing the *My.Project.Tests.csproj* and run `dotnet stryker` from the command line.  If there is only one project reference in the *My.Project.Tests.csproj* it will be automatically detected and Stryker will attempt to create mutants to check your Unit Test project.  If there are multiple project references in the *My.Project.Tests.csproj* file, then you will be asked to clarify which project you intend to mutate by passing the *--project-file*.

Personally I would create a stryker-config.json in the root of your unit testing project, as shown here: https://github.com/stryker-mutator/stryker-net/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md

You probably want something like this:

```
{
  "stryker-config": {
    "reporters": [
      "progress",
      "html"
    ],
    "log-level": "info",
    "log-file": true,
    "timeout-ms": 10000,
    "project-file": "My.Project.csproj",
    "max-concurrent-test-runners": 4,
    "threshold-high": 80,
    "threshold-low": 70,
    "threshold-break": 60,
    "mutation-level": "Standard",
    "excluded-mutations": [
      "string"
    ],
    "dashboard-compare": false
  }
}
```

Assuming My.Project.csproj is referenced in your unit test project.